# Custom Debian Package Installation Ubuntu Software Centre not asking sudo password(16.04 LTS)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, software-center, password

Created a Debian package which installs certain applications in the root folder. When double-clicking on the .deb file, Ubuntu Software Centre is not asking for password and it is not installing. However, using the terminal, the command "sudo dpkg -i testpack.deb" installs the application.

Any idea how to make the Ubuntu Software Centre ask for a password.

Thanks